# coinbase oauth2 redirect uri

Tags: redirect, meteor, oauth, package, coinbase-api

I'm rolling an accounts-coinbase meteor package and everything is fine except I keep getting an error from coinbase saying "the redirect uri included is not valid"  so I printed out the redirect uri and I don't see anything wrong with it.
This is the redirect url taken directly out of the popup from coinbase:

```
http://localhost:3000/_oauth/coinbase?close
```

I checked my coinbase application to see what I had as the callback url and this is a direcet copy:

```
http://localhost:3000/_oauth/coinbase?close
```

I am not sure why I am getting this error.

The code base can be found here:

https://github.com/khamoud/meteor-accounts-coinbase

Thanks in advance for what is probably a simple answer but I've been working on this problem for a while and I'm stuck.

Comment: hey @Kris, were you able to find a solution for this? I can't get anything to work.

Comment: Please note that Coinbase will only allow a `redirect_uri` that is whitelisted for your application.

Answer (score 1):

Your callback url is itself being included as a param in a *different* url, so it needs to be properly encoded. In your case, the `?` character in the callback url is causing problems.

```
encodeURIComponent('http://localhost:3000/_oauth/coinbase?close')
```

Answer (score 0):

I used `http://127.0.0.1:3000/` and it worked well for my app